# Why is this transistor in my bootstrap driver failing?

Tags: transistors, switches, bjt, mosfet-driver

I'm trying to implement a bootstrap switch circuit for an N-channel high side switch. I implemented the following circuit on a breadboard:

[image: Circuit Schematic]

[image: Breadboard Implementation]

Testing it with a 24V power supply and a grounded input signal resulted in the shown transistor blowing up. The control voltage was simply grounded and the circuit failed as soon as it was powered up.

Why would that transistor fail? It's connected to a floating switch node and the resistors in the network should be high enough for it not to blow up even when malfunctioning.

The transistors were purchased by on a Chinese website and are definitely poor quality, but they should still be able to handle this use case according to their datasheet.

EDIT: A possible reason for the transistor failure could be its maximum \$ V_{EB} = 6V \$ rating. What do you think?

Comment: How was it layed out for trace length and crosstalk?

Comment: Define "testing"; did you apply any signal to the input? Or did it fail as soon as the power supply was connected?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I edited the question adding the breadboard layout. I did not think it would be relevant.

Comment: @Hearth I connected the control input to ground and the circuit failed as soon as it was powered up.

Comment: Layout isn't relevant if the failure happens before you even switch anything. Unless it turns out you've made a mistake and connected something wrong, of course!

Comment: I'm thinking that a possible issue would be the lack of a base resistor on the first transistor. Base and emitter should not be short circuited, and that is likely causing some issues. What do you think?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with shorting the base to the emitter; that'll just hold the transistor off.

Comment: Okay so it's not that. In the datasheet, the maximum base-emitter voltage is listed at 6V, I think this might be the problem. In this circuit the emitter-base voltage reaches at least 12V.

Comment: A 2N6561 is a power NPN transistor. A 2N5561 is an n-type FET. So, what are you really using for that transistor?

Comment: You need an input base R, and also a base R for the PNP

Comment: The 24V exceeds FET gate voltage of 20V.

Comment: the 2N5551 almost looks like 2N5561 or 2N6561

Answer (score 3):

A couple of items in the design are not ideal:

1. The upper transistor is not driven heavily enough. When the input transistor is turned off current from the 6.8k resistor will enter the base of the 2N5551. This current will decrease as the voltage on the base (and MOSFET gate) rises. One easy improvement is to bootstrap the drive by returning Cboot to the emitters of the transistors rather than the source of the MOSFET. The voltage across the 6.8k resistor (and the current into the base of the NPN transistor) will remain almost constant throughout the cycle. This current will be about 3mA but may not be enough though.

You haven't specified the rise time needed but since the IRF244 has a gate charge of about 25nC it would take about 250mA to turn the device on or off in 100ns. To guarantee 250mA from the drive transistor would require more than 3mA drive. Maybe 10mA base drive would be adequate with a reasonable hFE device.

The lack of drive may be a factor in the failure of the device.

2. A 1N4001 is not ideal for the diode from the 24V supply. That series of diodes is very slow and can take many microseconds to conduct or to stop conducting. A shottky diode or faster silicon diode would be preferable.
3. 24V for gate drive is a bit high and endangers the MOSFET. There may be significant ringing that causes excessive gate voltage.
4. The construction on a solderless breadboard can result in excessive inductive and capacitative parasitics. A PCB is ideal but even a printed circuit prototype board with heavy short wiring to the sensitive modes will be an improvement.

PS. It would help the discussion if you put reference designators on the various components so posters could refer to the schematic more precisely. Or use the built-in schematic editor.

Answer (score 3):

It appears your breadboard has the transistors wired incorrectly. The 2N5551 & 2N5401 datasheets show a EBC pinout (looking at the front face) but you have wired as CBE. From memory the CBE is the more common BJT pinout - been  while since I've used TO-92.

If this is the case, the Base Emitter junctions will be be heavily reverse biased and breakdown. So yes the low VEB may be the culprit but only due to the wiring issue. In normal operation the BE junction should not be reversed biased.

Some other comments:

Your bootstrap supply is high at 24V. This will apply nearly 24V between the gate and source of the load MOSFET. This is outside the 20V Vgs rating of the MOSFET. Typically the bootstrap supply used is more like 12V. You may get way with it for bread boarding but I would not do this for ongoing use.

I'm not sure what you have planed for the input BJT. But as is you wont be able to apply an input voltage to the base. You could use base resistor but an emitter resistor is more typical. This will make the input BJT act like a constant current sink to the floating bootstrap section. This allows you to do things like reduce the 6k8 to get a fast/harder turn on but not have excessive power dissipation.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. In fact I was looking at [this dataheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/2N5550_5551.pdf) (CBE) from Nexperia but [this datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1725618.pdf) shows an EBC pinout. Hard to guess what the pinout for these transistors is, since the manufacturer is unknown.
I have connected the transistors as you suggested and the circuit seems to work.

Comment: @RiccardoFagiolo Note that the Nexperia datasheet shows the transistor pins from the bottom so it's consistent with E-B-C.

Answer (score 2):

First: Your input transistor is likely missing a base resistor. You do want a base resistor if your control signal is a voltage (as opposed to a current).

Your schematic looks reasonable. Your problem is most likely an incorrect connection. For instance, if you swap base and collector on the troublesome transistor, it will cost you a new transistor indeed. Add a resistor (10 - 100 Ohm) between the input transistor's collector and bases of the push-pull stage. This way you can limit (and observe!) the base current. Once you get the circuit working, remove the resistor if you need to.

Comment: I have added the base resistor, and changed all the semiconductor components. I've tested the circuit at 12V and it works fine. The only big change was the base resistor, is it possible that that was the issue? Could the 24V power supply be too high for those transistors?